# CSS :hover responds when I hover AROUND rather than OVER div element

Tags: css, hover, image-replacement

I'm having a subtle but annoying problem: I'm trying to implement a "Close" cross with a CSS image replacement. The HTML is

```
<div id='close' title='Close'>
    <a href='#'>
        <img src='https://dl.dropbox.com/u/116120595/images/tr_sq_30_30.png' />
    </a>
</div>
```

The image here is a 30px by 30px transparent square. The CSS is

```
div.fadeOut div#close{
    margin:5px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/116120595/images/blue_ccr_30_30.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}

div.fadeOut div#close:hover{
    background:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/116120595/images/red_ccr_30_30.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
}
```

The two images are transparent 30px by 30px squares, with a blue and red "Close" cross in them. The result doesn't work very well since `:hover` only seems to respond to me hovering **around** instead of **over** the `div`. Please see [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/116120595/images/hover_problem.swf) for a demo.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like another element is partly overlaying the close button. Try adding a `z-index` property and see if it helps. Also, a jsFiddle would have been a lot more helpful :)

Comment: @Boaz: you mean a `z-index` on the 30px by 30px `div` element, right?

Comment: A `z-index` to the `div#close` element, yes.

Comment: Great :) Posted it as an answer.

Comment: fix please formatting and add http://jsfiddle.net/ example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like another element is partly overlaying the close button. Try adding a `z-index` property to `div#close` and see if it helps. You probably have another `positioned` element with a higher `z-index` value.